# Design: Better to keep all POCO's in one Model.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

Design wise, I am struggling with where to keep items I use on the front-end for textboxes, radio button lists, etc.

My latest thought is to keep all the objects for a particular service I provide in one file. It would wind up being a 200+ line file, but keeps everything I use on that one service in one place. I have multiple services, so breaking up one service Model.cs file into several becomes a bit cumbersome. Plus, if I break them up into multiple models I run into the problem of needing bits from each model and then having to create a ViewModel.cs just to contain the sub-models when I present it in my View.cshtml file.

I may not have things correct.

The other problem I have is that I want to present different views for different solutions within the service. For example: I have Service 1 that I provide, and within that I want to be able to have 4 distinct things. 1) Quote. 2) Evaluation. 3) Consultation. 4) Solution.

Each builds on the former, so an Evaluation will also contain the elements of a Quote but also have its own elements. A Consultation will contain the elements of a Quote and Evaluation, and some of its own elements. And a Solution will contain all 3 of the former with its own elements.

Assume each has 10 elements. I could go the route of creating four Model.cs files for each, or one main one for all 40.

I know everyone has different design ideas, but I am wondering if going with one Model.cs file for all 40 elements will make my life easier than having 4 separate files of 10 elements, each of which is referenced in various solutions (requiring a fifth file to house all 4 Model.cs files).

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about common shared assembly with models? All your services should just reference the common models assembly.

Comment: I always assumed shared assemblies were something you might put in the GAC, and that the GAC was reserved for truly "global" items. In my situation, I just want the model items to be shared within my application, which is using multiple views (each view using different parts of the Model.cs). It sounds like I might be okay just having one big Model.cs file and pulling the appropriate things I need for a specific view (even if I am not using every item in the Model.cs). My biggest concern was "bloat", that is loading up a model with 40 items and only, in some instances, using only 10.

Comment: By "shared" I meant shared within your application parts, not GAC. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I could have opted for having multiple ViewModels and then tie them together using a BigViewModel, this would not work for my requirements. I have 4 distinct ViewModels, and in some instances would not need to use them all.

I've just opted to create one big model and pull from it as needed. I have not seen any significant performance hit, which is what my main concern was.